# Return to index.html if refresh is hit on a hashtag link

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, hashtag

I'm making a website, where the whole jQuery script I use acts weird, once someone hits refresh - so I thought that when someone refreshes, their URL changes from lets say `www.website.com/index.html#test` to just `www.website.com/index.html` ... Is this possible, if so, how?

Comment: Refreshing is going to 'refresh' the current page. So if your on `www.website.com/index.html#test` then its going to go back to the same address.

Comment: Intead can you tell use why/how exactly is it troubling you when/if the url is set to `website.com/index.html#test`? It seems like the problem is something else and **you are trying fix just the symptom**.

Comment: What should happen if someone navigates directly to `index.html#whatever`, should they have the hash stripped, or go to the specific portion of the page?

Comment: Yes well, the problem is. If you go to www.magnusk.dk/ny and click on the image to the top-right you go to the right, to find a grey page. Now the URL should be magnusk.dk/ny/#renluksus . You can go back to Portfolio and everything is fine! But if you refresh the page or to directly to http://magnusk.dk/ny/#renluksus and THEN go back to the portfolio, things are messed up. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check if the url contains hashes so:

```
var url=window.location;
if(url.indexOf('#')!=-1){
   window.location = 'index.html';
}
```

what the `indexOf` does is it checks if a string contains some substring and if it does then it returns the index of where that substring is and if it dosen't find it then it returns -1 so
what we did there is we checked if it't not equal to -1 so that means the substring exists then we want to go to index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) 
{
    window.location = "index.html#introduction";
};
```

This lets you redirect a refresh to another section but it didn't seem to work redirecting to index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my application. I was a vanilla HTML, vanilla JS and vanilla CSS application.

```js
window.addEventListener("hashchange", onRouteChanged);

function onRouteChanged() {
    const hash = window.location.hash;

    const routerView = document.getElementById("router-view");

    if (!(routerView instanceof HTMLElement)) {
        throw new ReferenceError("No router view element available for rendering");
    }

    switch (hash) {
        case '#about':
            routerView.innerHTML = `<section id="about">
                                        <div class="title-box">
                                            <h3>About</h3>
                                            <hr/>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4></h4>
                                        <footer>
                                            <span>© 2023 Creator of The Quotes Room</span>
                                        </footer>
                                    </section>`;
            about();
            break;
        case "#home":
            window.location = "index.html"
            break;
        default:
            routerView.innerHTML = "<h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>";
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <section>
            <img src="img/Quotes room.png" alt="logo" target="logo">
            <h1>The Quotes Room</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Search.."></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </header>
```

So as you can see, I used the hash for routing from a page to another one. A for me, it worked with:

```
window.location = "index.html"
```